# SQL Error in the Clause Definitions

Tags: sql

I have a query but it is giving me a Cannot insert duplicate key in object error. I know I need to include a where not exists statement but no matter where I try I get errors. Any idea where it would go in this?

```
INSERT ProductCustomerLevel 
(
ProductID,
CustomerLevel
)
SELECT ProductID,
CustomerLevel
FROM dbo.Product p
CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 5 AS CustomerLevel UNION ALL
        SELECT 7
        )c
```

Comment: What is the primary key? ProductID, or ProductID and CustomerLevel?

Comment: this query will add two values for each ProductID from dbo.Products into ProductCustomerLevel , one with Level 5 and one with level 7, if you have ProductID set as primary key it will throw an error as Primary key column cannot have multiple values in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume that the Primary Key is `(ProductID, CustomerLevel)` you could try something like

```
SELECT ProductID,
CustomerLevel
FROM dbo.Product p
CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 5 AS CustomerLevel UNION ALL
        SELECT 7
        )c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT  1
                    FROM    ProductCustomerLevel pcl
                    WHERE   p.ProductID = pcl.ProductID
                    AND     c.CustomerLevel = pcl.CustomerLevel
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this before you run the insert:

```
DELETE FROM ProductCustomerLevel 
WHERE CustomerLevel IN (5, 7)
```